# Unit testing for mutation RTK Query with fixedCacheKey

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, rtk-query

I'm currently running RTK Queries for my project and i'm stuck on how to test `ComponentTwo`.

The below is from the RTK Query doco and is it the exact same scenario I'm in.

For me, in `ComponentOne` I used the `updatePost` trigger function to get a response from the API and use that response result in `ComponentTwo` (`ComponentTwo` is one a different page)

What is the best way to test `ComponentTwo`?

Should I mock `useUpdatePostMutation` using spyOn? or is there a more 'elegant' way?

Thank you very much!

```
export const ComponentOne = () => {
  // Triggering `updatePostOne` will affect the result in both this component,
  // but as well as the result in `ComponentTwo`, and vice-versa
  const [updatePost, result] = useUpdatePostMutation({
    fixedCacheKey: 'shared-update-post',
  })

  return <div>...</div>
}

export const ComponentTwo = () => {
  const [updatePost, result] = useUpdatePostMutation({
    fixedCacheKey: 'shared-update-post',
  })

  return <div> {result.data.post}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to test the behavior of the `fixedCacheKey` option,  RTKQ already tested it.
2. You should use [msw](https://mswjs.io/), [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) and so on to mock the API based on the library you use to handle the requests.
3. Assert what will be rendered of `ComponentTwo` after calling the `updatePost` in `ComponentOne`.

e.g.(*There is no real HTTP request, the endpoint returns the argument as data for demostration*)

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const api = createApi({
  async baseQuery(arg: string | Promise<string>) {
    return { data: await arg };
  },
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    updatePost: build.mutation<string, string | Promise<string>>({
      query: (arg) => arg,
    }),
  }),
});
const { useUpdatePostMutation } = api;

export const ComponentOne = ({ name }: { name: string }) => {
  const [updatePost, result] = useUpdatePostMutation({
    fixedCacheKey: 'shared-update-post',
  });

  return (
    <div data-testid={name}>
      <div data-testid="status">{result.status}</div>
      <div data-testid="data">{result.data}</div>
      <div data-testid="originalArgs">{String(result.originalArgs)}</div>
      <button data-testid="trigger" onClick={() => updatePost(name)}>
        trigger
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export const ComponentTwo = ({ name }: { name: string }) => {
  const [updatePost, result] = useUpdatePostMutation({
    fixedCacheKey: 'shared-update-post',
  });

  return (
    <div data-testid={name}>
      <div data-testid="status">{result.status}</div>
      <div data-testid="data">{result.data}</div>
      <div data-testid="originalArgs">{String(result.originalArgs)}</div>
      <button data-testid="trigger" onClick={() => updatePost(name)}>
        trigger
      </button>
      <button data-testid="reset" onClick={result.reset}>
        reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { act, getByTestId, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ComponentOne, ComponentTwo, api } from '.';
import React from 'react';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

describe('77170397', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
        [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
      },
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(api.middleware),
    });
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ComponentOne name="c1" />
        <ComponentTwo name="c2" />
      </Provider>,
    );

    const c1 = screen.getByTestId('c1');
    const c2 = screen.getByTestId('c2');
    expect(getByTestId(c1, 'status').textContent).toBe('uninitialized');
    expect(getByTestId(c2, 'status').textContent).toBe('uninitialized');

    act(() => {
      getByTestId(c1, 'trigger').click();
    });

    await waitFor(() => expect(getByTestId(c1, 'status').textContent).toBe('fulfilled'));

    expect(getByTestId(c1, 'data').textContent).toBe('c1');
    expect(getByTestId(c2, 'status').textContent).toBe('fulfilled');
    expect(getByTestId(c2, 'data').textContent).toBe('c1');
    expect(getByTestId(c2, 'status').textContent).toBe('fulfilled');
  });
});
```